# make bootstrap columns overlap each other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am trying to make 1 bootstrap column overlap the other, where one column is shorter than the other.[image: columns]

I am not sure how to achieve this, Is it done using `bootstrap`'s `offset` classes? How would I go about it?

My code so far:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3" style="background-color: blue; height: 100px;">
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-3" style="background-color: orange; height: 200px;">
      <img src="#" class="img-fluid">
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not comfortable with bootstrap, but I tried it with html and CSS and it worked, you just need to add a margin with a negative value ( also not to forget to mention that you mistyped `background-colour` it should be `background-color`.

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3" style="background-color: blue; height: 300px;margin-right:-40px;z-index:1">
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-3" style="background-color: orange; height: 400px;">
      <img src="#" class="img-fluid">
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction about `background-colour`, edited my post. Your answer doesn't solve my issue fully, the column is not in the middle of the other

Comment: ok did that worked for you? if it did mark my answer as correct so others can benefit. @koder613